# Set method not entered when ConcurrentDictionary is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I have a `ConcurrentDictionary` on a static class as such:

```
static class MyData
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lot> _inventory;
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lot> Inventory
    {
        get
        {
            return _inventory;
        }
        set
        {
            _inventory = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to intercept changes being made in the setter to execute some logic, but when I use this code to update from another class, I'm not seeing the set method being entered.

```
MyData.Inventory.AddOrUpdate(lotID, lot, (key, oldValue) => lot);
```

Comment: You enter only `get` accessor, e.g. get the instance and call `AddOrUpdate(lotID, lot, (key, oldValue) => lot);`

Comment: Setter will **only** be called if you use `Inventory = something;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the `Inventory` property. You're getting it.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
var inventory = MyData.Inventory;
inventory.AddOrUpdate(lotID, lot, (key, oldValue) => lot);
```

You can see that you're *getting* `MyData.Inventory`, not *setting* it.

If you wrote code which did this:

```
MyData.Inventory = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lot>();
```

*then* you would be setting `MyData.Inventory`, and your setter would be called.

You can achieve what you want my encapsulating the `ConcurrentDictionary` inside your class. (It looks like you actually want always set the `Lot` for a given `lotId`, so I've updated the code to do this).

```
static class MyData
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lot> _inventory = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lot>();

    public static Update(string lotId, Lot lot)
    {
        // Add your interception code here
        _inventory[lotId] = lot;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Makes sense.